# Why a struct declared by let can be changed?

Tags: swift, struct, let, unsafemutablepointer

In the following code, 'ptr' is a struct declared by let, but its member variable 'pointee' could be changed, Why?

    `let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity:1)
    ptr.pointee = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UnsafeMutablePointer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer) *is* a struct, but it declares

```
public struct UnsafeMutablePointer<Pointee> : Strideable, Hashable {

    public var pointee: Pointee { get nonmutating set }
    public subscript(i: Int) -> Pointee { get nonmutating set }

}
```

Here "nonmutating set" means that setting the property does not mutate
the state of the pointer variable itself.

Therefore `ptr.pointee` can be assigned a new value even if `ptr`
is a constant, and the same is true for the subscript setter:

```
let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity:1)
ptr.pointee = 1
ptr[0] = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, `ptr` is constant, so you cannot assign a new `UnsafeMutablePointer` to it, but the structure it holds within can be modified. In short, you cannot reassign anything to a `let` entity, but you can access and modify its properties.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is not a struct.

It's a reference type unlike a struct which is value type.

Since you declare the pointer as mutable you can change the `pointee` (the contents of the memory) but you cannot change the reference itself.

Comment: @DávidPásztor The pointer is declared as *Unsafe**Mutable**Pointer*

Comment: my bad, I thought you meant the declaration to be mutable/immutable, not the type of the pointer itself.

Comment: `struct UnsafeMutablePointer` is a struct.

Answer (score 1):

In case of a Pointer, you cannot change the memory address it is pointing to, but you can change the data stored at that memory address.
The Pointer is only storing a reference to a memory address, so as long as that address is constant, the Pointer didn't change its value.